# Write a function lines(a) that determines how many balls will be destroyed

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

some balls of different colors in a line. When a continuous block of **three or more** balls of the same color is formed, it is removed from the line. In this case, all the balls are shifted to each other, and the situation may be repeated.

Write a function lines(a) that determines how many balls will be destroyed. There can be at most one continuous block of three or more same-colored balls at the initial moment.

Input data:

The function takes a list a with initial balls disposition. Balls number is less or equals 1000, balls colors can be from 0 to 9, each color has its own integer.

Output data:

The function has to return one number, the number of the balls that will be destroyed.

```
Input:[2,2,1,1,1,2,1] Output:6

input : [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], output: 5

input:[2, 3, 1, 4], output: 0
```

I try to use the two pointer approach, but not sure how to do it.

```
def lines(a):
    left = 0
    right = len(a)-1
    s=[]
    while left < right :
        if a[left] == a[left:right+1]:
            s.extend(a[left: right+1])
            del a[left: right+1]
        else:
            left += 1
            right -= 1
    return len(s) 
test_a = [2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1]
print(lines(test_a))
```

I think `if a[left] == a[left:right+1]:` did not work, i am  try to compare elements from left to right is same as elements from right to left. Also`del a[left: right+1]` did not work, i try delete those elements which already extend to new list s.

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: What do you mean by: `The function has to return one number, the number of the balls that will be destroyed.`?

Comment: @Ahx if the test case is [2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1], After three balls color of 1 were destroyed, balls shifted to the left and new disposition [2, 2, 2, 1] appears. Three balls color of 2 were destroyed too. so total 6 balls were destroyed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an iterative solution using a `lo` and `hi` pointer traversing the input.

Note that by appending an end marker guaranteed *not* to be an input colour means that the logic checking for runs of colours does not need duplication outside the while loop.

**The code**

```
in_outs = [([2,2,1,1,1,2,1], 6),
           ([0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 5),
           ([2, 3, 1, 4], 0),
           ]

def test(f):
    print(f"\nSTART Testing answer {f.__doc__}")
    for arg, ans in in_outs:
        try:
            out = f(arg.copy())
        except:
            ans = '<Exception thrown!>'
        if out != ans:
            print(f" {f.__name__}({arg}) != {ans} # instead gives: {out}")
        else:
            print(f" {f.__name__}({arg}) == {out}")
    print(f"STOP  Testing answer {f.__doc__}\n")

#%% From me, Paddy3118

def lines(a):
    "From Paddy3118"
    a = a.copy() + [-1]         # Add terminator
    d = lo = hi = 0             # delete count, lo & hi pointers
    lo_c = hi_c = a[0]          # Colours at pointer positions
    while hi +1 < len(a):
        hi += 1; hi_c = a[hi]
        if lo_c != hi_c:
            if hi - lo > 2:
                d += hi - lo
                del a[lo: hi]
                lo, hi, lo_c, hi_c = 0, 0, a[0], a[0]
            else:
                lo, lo_c = hi, hi_c
    return d

test(lines)
```

**Output**

```
START Testing answer From Paddy3118
 lines([2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1]) == 6
 lines([0, 0, 0, 0, 0]) == 5
 lines([2, 3, 1, 4]) == 0
STOP  Testing answer From Paddy3118
```

**Checking other examples**

Extend the above with the following harnesses to aid testing

```
#%% IA from Ignacio Alorre

import itertools
def grouping_balls(balls):
    return ["".join(g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(balls)]

def destroy_balls(list_balls, destroyed):
    if len(list_balls) < 1:
        return destroyed
    balls_grp = grouping_balls(list_balls)
    # No more balls to destroy
    if max(map(len,balls_grp)) < 3:
        return destroyed
    # Destroying and merging balls
    else:
        non_dest_balls = ""
        for l in balls_grp:
            if len(l) < 3:
                non_dest_balls += l
            else:
                destroyed += len(l)
        return destroy_balls(non_dest_balls, destroyed)

def lines_IA(a):
    "From Ignacio Alorre"
    return destroy_balls(''.join(map(str, a)), 0)

test(lines_IA)

#%% AHX from Ahx

total_destroyed = 0
counter = 0
previous = -1
previous_index = -1


def _lines_ahx(a):
    """
    Args:
        a (list): input array

    Returns:
        (int): total number of destroyed balls.
    """
    global total_destroyed
    global counter
    global previous
    global previous_index

    for i, element in enumerate(a):
        if element == previous:
            counter += 1
        else:
            counter = 1
            previous = element
            previous_index = i

        if counter >= 3:
            for _ in range(previous_index, i+1):
                a.pop(previous_index)
                total_destroyed += 1
            _lines_ahx(a)

    return total_destroyed

def lines_AHX(a):
    "From Ahx"
    global total_destroyed
    global counter
    global previous
    global previous_index

    total_destroyed = 0
    counter = 0
    previous = -1
    previous_index = -1

    return _lines_ahx(a)


test(lines_AHX)
```

**Full Output**

All three examples work on the given testds. No timings are given as the tests are very small.

```
START Testing answer From Paddy3118
 lines([2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1]) == 6
 lines([0, 0, 0, 0, 0]) == 5
 lines([2, 3, 1, 4]) == 0
STOP  Testing answer From Paddy3118


START Testing answer From Ignacio Alorre
 lines_IA([2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1]) == 6
 lines_IA([0, 0, 0, 0, 0]) == 5
 lines_IA([2, 3, 1, 4]) == 0
STOP  Testing answer From Ignacio Alorre


START Testing answer From Ahx
 lines_AHX([2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1]) == 6
 lines_AHX([0, 0, 0, 0, 0]) == 5
 lines_AHX([2, 3, 1, 4]) == 0
STOP  Testing answer From Ahx
```

Comment: thanks, i like your Lo Hi pointer solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use a stack for this (simple list implementation). Check if the last 3 balls are of the same kind. If they are, then keep popping all balls of the same kind. Else, add the ball to the stack and continue. Each ball can be added once and removed once to the list, so the complexity should be O(N) as well.
At the end, number of balls destroyed = count of original balls - length of stack.

Comment: you need consider the case when more than 3 balls are same. like [0,0,0,0,0] output is 5.

Comment: @AcatAdog considered that

Answer (score 0):

We need to count the number of occurrences in the input list.

If the current ball color (`element`) is equals to the previous ball color (`previous`), then increase the counter by one.

```py
for i, element in enumerate(a):
    if element == previous:
        counter += 1
```

If they are not equal, then there will be a possibility the next color may repeat more than three. Therefore store the current colors' index

```py
for i, element in enumerate(a):
    if element == previous:
        counter += 1
    else:
        counter = 1
        previous = element
        previous_index = i
```

Now check if the color is repeated more than three times.

If it does we need to remove the balls from the list.

While removing we also need to count the number of destroyed balls.

```py
if counter >= 3:
    for _ in range(previous_index, i+1):
        a.pop(previous_index)
        total_destroyed += 1
```

There might be a confusion, why I did `a.pop(previous_index)`?

If you debug this part of code on an example. For instance: `[2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1]`

When `i`== 4, the current list is `[2, 2, 1, 1, 1]` which satisfies the `count >= 3`

- Iteration = 1, the list will become

```py
[2, 2, 1, 1]
```

If you say remove the next element, which will pop the final element

- Iteration = 2, the list will become

```py
[2, 2, 1]
```

Now, on Iteration 3, which element will be pop? index-out-of-bound.

- Iteration = 3, the list won't change

```py
[2, 2, 1]
```

Therefore, during the iteration always pop the current element. Since the next element will be the current one.

Now we need to call the method again, to see if there is any balls left

```py
if counter >= 3:
    for _ in range(previous_index, i+1):
        a.pop(previous_index)
        total_destroyed += 1
    lines(a)
```

But, we have to be careful since we have declared `previous`, `previous_index`, `counter` and `totally_destroyed` as a local variable.

If we keep them as a local attributes, all variables will be re-iniitalized so the alogrithm result won't be true.

Therefore we have to initialize them as a global variable and return the total number of destroyed balls.

Code:

```py
total_destroyed = 0
counter = 0
previous = -1
previous_index = -1


def lines(a):
    """
    Args:
        a (list): input array

    Returns:
        (int): total number of destroyed balls.
    """
    global total_destroyed
    global counter
    global previous
    global previous_index

    for i, element in enumerate(a):
        if element == previous:
            counter += 1
        else:
            counter = 1
            previous = element
            previous_index = i

        if counter >= 3:
            for _ in range(previous_index, i+1):
                a.pop(previous_index)
                total_destroyed += 1
            lines(a)

    return total_destroyed


test_a = [2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1]
test_b = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
test_c = [2, 3, 1, 4]
print(lines(test_a))
total_destroyed = 0
counter = 0
previous = -1
previous_index = -1
print(lines(test_b))
total_destroyed = 0
counter = 0
previous = -1
previous_index = -1
print(lines(test_c))
```

Results:

```
6
5
0
```

Comment: Popping the list multiple times will be an expensive operation

Comment: It makes expensive use of recursion. Try [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]

Answer (score 0):

My solution has two parts. One method to group by balls by their number `grouping_balls`. Then a recursive method first check there are still groups bigger than 3, if so destroy them and merge the rest for the next iteration `destroy_balls`.

```
import itertools

# Split balls by type
# For 2211121 you would get: ["22", "111", "2", "1"]
def grouping_balls(balls):
    return ["".join(g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(balls)]

# Keeps destroying balls as long as there are groups of 3 or more
def destroy_balls(list_balls, destroyed):
    if len(list_balls) < 1:
        return destroyed
    balls_grp = grouping_balls(list_balls)
    # No more balls to destroy
    if max(map(len,balls_grp)) < 3:
        return destroyed
    # Destroying and merging balls
    else:
        non_dest_balls = ""
        for l in balls_grp:
            if len(l) < 3:
                non_dest_balls += l
            else:
                destroyed += len(l)
        return destroy_balls(non_dest_balls, destroyed)

Input = [0,0,0,0,0]
destroy_balls(''.join(map(str,Input)), 0)
```

Comment: You don't RETURN a value, you print it. Throws an exception on input [0,0,0,0,0].

Comment: I tried running what you posted and that last line is a copy-paste error and I get 0 ?

Comment: @Paddy3118 ay!, thanks again, not able to be into two things at the same time. Now you should be getting 5

Answer (score 0):

I thought of another algorithm that first does a run-length encoding of the whole input before using a single pointer traversing the list and deleting stuff. It works a lot better on larger input.

To test it I wrote a routine `downto_zero` that generates sequences of ones and zeroes which are all deleted, eventually.

I follow up by doing a timed run of all the examples.

Note: run in Ipython shell of Spyder IDE for timings.

Note: the example for Ahx makes great use of recursion and fails with an input of length 12, let alone 7500.

**RLE code and Test Generator**

```
#%% Test Generator for long tests

in_outs = [([2,2,1,1,1,2,1], 6),
           ([0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 5),
           ([2, 3, 1, 4], 0),
           ]

import sys

def test(f, in_outs=in_outs):
    print(f"\nSTART Testing answer {f.__doc__}")
    for arg, ans in in_outs:
        arg_txt = arg if len(arg) <= 8 else f"[<{len(arg)} terms>]"
        try:
            out = f(arg.copy())
        except:
            out = f'<Exception thrown! {sys.exc_info()[0]}>'
        if out != ans:
            print(f" {f.__name__}({arg_txt}) != {ans} # instead gives: {out}")
        else:
            print(f" {f.__name__}({arg_txt}) == {out}")
    print(f"STOP  Testing answer {f.__doc__}\n")

def downto_zero(n=3):
    "Test generator that reduces all input"
    if n == 0:
        return []
    x = ([0, 1] * ((n+1)//2))[:n]       # 0,1 ... of length n
    e = x[-1]                           # end item
    ne = 0 if e == 1 else 1             # not end item
    r = ([e, e, ne, ne] * n)[:2*n]
    return x + r


#%% RLE Runlengh encoded from me, Paddy

from itertools import groupby

def lines_RLE(a):
    "From Paddy3118 using run-length encoding"
    a = a.copy() + [-1]         # Add terminator
    a = [[key, len(list(group))] for key, group in groupby(a)] # RLE
    d = pt = 0                  # delete count, pointer
    while pt +1 < len(a):
        i0, n0 = a[pt]          # item, count at pt
        if n0 > 2:
            d += n0
            del a[pt]
            if pt > 0:
                if a[pt - 1][0] == a[pt][0]:    # consolidate
                    a[pt - 1][1] += a[pt][1]
                    del a[pt]
                    pt -= 1
            continue
        else:
            pt += 1

    return d

test(lines_RLE, in_outs)

#%% Timed testing

print("TIMED TESTING\n=============")
n = 2_500
for f in (lines, lines_RLE, lines_IA, lines_AHX):
    dn = downto_zero(n)
    %time test(f, [(dn, len(dn))])
```

**Output with timings**

```
START Testing answer From Paddy3118 using run-length encoding
 lines_RLE([2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1]) == 6
 lines_RLE([0, 0, 0, 0, 0]) == 5
 lines_RLE([2, 3, 1, 4]) == 0
STOP  Testing answer From Paddy3118 using run-length encoding

TIMED TESTING
=============

START Testing answer From Paddy3118
 lines([<7500 terms>]) == 7500
STOP  Testing answer From Paddy3118

Wall time: 2.44 s

START Testing answer From Paddy3118 using run-length encoding
 lines_RLE([<7500 terms>]) == 7500
STOP  Testing answer From Paddy3118 using run-length encoding

Wall time: 19 ms

START Testing answer From Ignacio Alorre
 lines_IA([<7500 terms>]) == 7500
STOP  Testing answer From Ignacio Alorre

Wall time: 10.9 s

START Testing answer From Ahx
 lines_AHX([<7500 terms>]) != 7500 # instead gives: <Exception thrown! <class 'RecursionError'>>
STOP  Testing answer From Ahx

Wall time: 16 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

My third, and last answer builds on my second RLE entry by swapping to use a doubly linked list data structure to remove what can be costly array delete operations. The new code looks like it has better big-O characteristics compared to my other two solutions so may proove even faster for larger inputs.

**Doubly-Linked list code:**

```
#%% LL Linked-list and Runlengh encoded from me, Paddy

from itertools import groupby

def lines_LL(a):
    "From Paddy3118 using a linked-list and run-length encoding"
    a = a.copy() + [-1]         # Add terminator

    # a is list of [item, reps, prev_pointer, next_pointer]
    a = [[key, len(list(group)), i - 1, i + 1]
         for i, (key, group) in enumerate(groupby(a))] # linke-list RLE
    a[0][-2] = None                     # No previous item
    a[-1][-1] = None                    # No next item

    d = pt = 0                          # delete count, pointer
    while pt is not None:
        i0, n0, pre_pt, nxt_pt = a[pt]          # item, count, next at pt
        if n0 > 2:
            d += n0
            deleted_pt = pt
            if pre_pt is not None:
                a[pre_pt][-1] = pt = nxt_pt     # del a[pt] & pt to next
                if a[pre_pt][0] == a[pt][0]:    # consolidate same items in pre
                    a[pre_pt][1] += a[pt][1]
                    a[pre_pt][-1] = a[pt][-1]   # del a[pt]
                    pt = pre_pt                 # ... & pt to previous
            else:
                pt = nxt_pt
        else:
            pt = nxt_pt

    return d

print("SIMPLE FUNCTIONAL TESTING\n=============")
test(lines_LL, in_outs)

#%% Timed testing

if 1:
    print("TIMED TESTING\n=============")
    n = 20_000
    for f in (lines_LL, lines_RLE, lines):  #, lines_IA, lines_AHX):
        dn = downto_zero(n)
        %time test(f, [(dn, len(dn))])
```

**Output and timings**

```
SIMPLE FUNCTIONAL TESTING
=============

START Testing answer From Paddy3118 using a linked-list and run-length encoding
 lines_LL([2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1]) == 6
 lines_LL([0, 0, 0, 0, 0]) == 5
 lines_LL([2, 3, 1, 4]) == 0
STOP  Testing answer From Paddy3118 using a linked-list and run-length encoding

TIMED TESTING
=============

START Testing answer From Paddy3118 using a linked-list and run-length encoding
 lines_LL([<60000 terms>]) == 60000
STOP  Testing answer From Paddy3118 using a linked-list and run-length encoding

Wall time: 104 ms

START Testing answer From Paddy3118 using run-length encoding
 lines_RLE([<60000 terms>]) == 60000
STOP  Testing answer From Paddy3118 using run-length encoding

Wall time: 387 ms

START Testing answer From Paddy3118
 lines([<60000 terms>]) == 60000
STOP  Testing answer From Paddy3118

Wall time: 2min 31s
```