# Remove triplets of adjacent numbers from the list

Tags: python

Here is the problem. The input is a list of integers. If three adjacent numbers appear next to each other they should be dropped and the operation goes again. Iphone app with the balls of the same colors. The output should be the count of the balls that will be destroyed.

Example:

```
input = [3,3,4,4,4,3,4]
```

1st iteration

```
output: [3,3,3,4]
```

Final output:

```
6
```

4,4,4 on the first iteration, so three balls. and 3,3,3 on the second. Overall six.

My code is below. It will remove the 4,4,4 but will fail after, because list index will quickly go out of range.

```
    def balls(a):
    
        curr_index = 0
        removed_count = 0
        while len(a) > 2:

            if (a[curr_index] == a[curr_index+1]) and (a[curr_index] == a[curr_index+2]):

                a.remove(a[curr_index])
                a.remove(a[curr_index+1])
                a.remove(a[curr_index+2])

            curr_index += 1
            removed_count += 3

        return removed_count

a = [3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4]
    
print(balls(a)) # should print 6
```

Any ideas?

Comment: you are doing `while len(a) > 3`. this isn't taking `curr_index` into account. do`while len(a)-curr_index > 3`

Comment: whet heppens when you've 4 or more?

Comment: are you allowed to use any librabries?

Comment: are you allowed to use regex? :)

Comment: @Dieter, first three drop, fourth remains. and I am not allowed to use regex or libraries.

Comment: how import is the order?  --> [ 2 2 1 1 1 2 3 3 3 2 2  ]  ---> will this become:   2 2 2 3 3 3 2 2 ---> 2 2 2 3 3 3 2 --> 3 3 3 2 2  -->  2 2   OR   2 2 2 2 2

Comment: @Dieter first occurrence of a triplet drops, so 22 will be the final output. I feel like recursion is needed here. Not sure how to implement it though.

Comment: @Johnnysmith - all recursion are replaceable by for loops (and are better for the memory))

Comment: Your code never handles a number not being part of a row of 3. It only increments curr_index when it adds 3 to removed count, but it should also increment it if not all the elements are equal

Comment: Do you go to the same class of this guy https://stackoverflow.com/q/65769822/1773841? Well, there you have more answers for what I believe is the same problem

Comment: *"If three adjacent numbers appear next to each other"* - Huh? Appearing next to each other is what being adjacent means...

Comment: As already stated by @IgnacioAlorre, a similar and better phrased question exists  here:  <stackoverflow.com/q/65769822/1773841>; this one should be closed or the two merged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
input_values = [3,3,4,4,4,3,4]


values = input_values
while len(values) >= 3:
    for x in range(0,len(values)-2):    
        
        # if we find 3 values in ar row
        if values[x] == values[x+1] and values[x] == values[x+2]:
            
            # update values by cutting out the series
            values = values[:x] + values[x+3:]
            
            # break this for loop
            break
    else:
        # for loops can have an else statement
        # this means that we came at the end of the for loop
        # this if we didn't break the loop (and didn't found a valid triple)
        # then we brea
        break
   
#result  - amount of removed balls     
values, len(input_values) - len(values)
```

Comment: hey @dieter, thank you! works. Just in case it's not a huge lift. How the above code will change for 3+ numbers in a row? we would need to track the left and the right index of the group of identical numbers?

Comment: - well you move from left to right:   thus basically you only need to know when the righter numbers changes

Comment: Could also use the simpler `while True`. And comparison chaining.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

```
your_list=[3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4]

def remove_one(l):
    if len(l)>2:
        for i in range(len(l)-2):
            if l[i]==l[i+1]==l[i+2]:
                res.extend(l[i:i+3])
                l=l[:i]+l[i+3:]
                return l
    return []

res=[]
while len(your_list)>2:
    your_list=remove_one(your_list)

print(len(res))
```

Output:

```
6
```

Answer (score 1):

### A more generic approach where you can define N

(it will find exact N values)

```py
input_values = [3,3,4,4,4,4,3,3,4]

# amount of neighbours
N = 4

values = input_values

# keep looping as long as we've N values
while len(values) >= N:
    
    # we need this if we break the inner loop
    stop = False
    
    # loop over values from left to right
    # 3 -> 3 -> 4 -> 4 -> ... until  -N + 1
    # because that is the last spot that we've N values left 
    for x in range(0, len(values) - N + 1):    
        
      
        # scout for the next numbers (x+1 x+2 x+3 ....)
        # this goes from, x+1 until the end of the serie
        # also start counting from 2 - because
        # if we've a single match, 2 numbers are equal
        for e, y in enumerate(range(x+1, len(values)), start=2):
            
            # if x and y are different, the stop this scouting
            # remember y = x+1   x+2  x+3 ....
            if values[x] != values[y]:
                break
  
            # if we reached this stage, we know that 
            # x and x+1     x+2   ... are equal
            # but also check if we've enough matches
            if e == N:
                # update values by cutting out the series
                values = values[:x] + values[y+1:]
                stop = True
                break
        
        if stop:
            break
 
      
    else:
        # for loops can have an else statement
        # this means that we came at the end of the for loop
        # this if we didn't break the loop (and didn't found a valid triple)
        # then we brea
        break
        
values, len(input_values) - len(values)
```

Comment: well it is generic to determine sequences of specified length. but I am more asking about dropping any identical sequence longer than N and count the removed items, so [0,0,0,0,0] would be 5 and [2,2, 3,3,3,3,3, 4,5,5,5,0,0,0,0,0] would be 13, and finally [2,2,0,0,0,0,2,2,3,3,3] would be 11.

Answer (score 1):

### An approach with a minimal threshold

```py
input_values = [3,3,4,4,4,4,4,3,3,4]

# threshold
N = 3

values = input_values
while len(values) >= N:
    
    # we need this if we break the inner loop
    stop = False
    
    # loop over values
    for x in range(0, len(values) - N + 1):    
        
        # scout for the next numbers (x+1 x+2 x+3 ....)
        for e, y in enumerate(range(x+1, len(values)), start=2):

            # check if the values of x and  x+1   (x+2  x+3 ...) are different
            if values[x] != values[y]:
                
                # if so, check if we've reached our threshold of N
                if e >= N:
                
                    # if this is the case update values by cutting out the series
                    values = values[:x] + values[y:]
                    stop = True
                    break
                    
                # if x+n  != x then we break this scouting loop
                break

        # stop is True, this means, that we found N neibouring numbers
        # thus we can break this loop, and start over with a new* value
        if stop:
            break
 
      
    else:
        # for loops can have an else statement
        # this means that we came at the end of the for loop
        # thus if we didn't break the loop (and didn't found a valid triple)
        # then we break
        break
        
values, len(input_values) - len(values)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with your code.

The first is you're trying to iterate over the list a single time, but that won't work for your example.

The second is you're assuming the list will always reduce to less than 3, which won't be the case if you have more numbers.

There are also some places you can simplify the syntax, for example:

`if (a[curr_index] == a[curr_index+1]) and (a[curr_index] == a[curr_index+2]):`

is equivalent to:

`if a[curr_index] == a[curr_index + 1] == a[curr_index + 2]:`

And

```
a.remove(a[curr_index])
a.remove(a[curr_index+1])
a.remove(a[curr_index+2])
```

is equivalent to:

`del a[curr_index: curr_index + 3]`

So here is one way to accomplish this, thought there are more efficient ways.

```
def balls(a):

    removed = 0
    complete = False

    # Run until complete is set or the list is too short for a match
    while not complete and len(a) >= 3:

        for idx, val in enumerate(a):
            if val == a[idx + 1] == a[idx + 2]:
                del a[idx: idx + 3]
                removed += 3
                break  # Restart every time we find a match

            # If it's the last possible match, set complete
            if idx == len(a) - 3:
                complete = True
                break

    return removed
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm little bit late, but my idea is to do the processing in one pass. The idea is that when you drop a tripple, go back two positions to re-check if a new tripple has been created by that change.

Example:

```
3 3 4 4 4 3
    ^--- tripple found here, remove it
3 3 3
^--- move the cursor 2 positions left and continue checking
```

The code:

```
def drop3(lst):
    # drop3 destroys the lst, make a copy if you want to keep it
    dropped = 0 
    cursor = 0 
    limit = len(lst) - 2 
    while cursor < limit:
        if lst[cursor] == lst[cursor+1] == lst[cursor+2]:
            del lst[cursor:cursor+3]
            cursor = max(0, cursor-2)
            limit -= 3
            dropped += 3
        else:
            cursor += 1
    return dropped
```

Answer (score 0):

A linear-tme solution:

```
def balls(a):
    b = []
    for x in a:
        b.append(x)
        if b[-3:] == [x] * 3:
            del b[-3:]
    return len(a) - len(b)
```