# Python remove N consecutive duplicates from the list

Tags: python

Here's the problem. The input is a list of integers. If more than three adjacent numbers appear next to each other they should be dropped and the operation goes again. Kind of similar to the Iphone game, where player needs to pop lines of three or more balls of the same colors. The output should be the count of the balls that will be removed.

The algorithm is as follows. Starting with a sample list of say [3,3,4,4,4,4,3,2].
First iteration should remove the 4,4,4,4 - so the list would become [3,3,3,2], and the intermediary output of removed numbers will be 4.
Second iteration should remove 3,3,3 - so the final list would be [2] and final count of removed numbers - 7.

The first implementation for three consecutive items came from another stackoverflow thread - [Remove triplets of adjacent numbers from the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65776574/remove-triplets-of-adjacent-numbers-from-the-list/65777752?noredirect=1#comment116299534_65777752)

Here's the working function implementation for exactly 3 consecutive numbers:

```
def balls(l):

    values = l

    while len(values) >= 3:
        print(values) #for demonstrative purposes of this question
        for x in range(0,len(values)-2):    
            if values[x] == values[x+1] and values[x] == values[x+2]:
                values = values[:x] + values[x+3:]
                break
        else:
            break

    print(values) #for demonstrative purposes of this question
   
    return len(l) - len(values)

balls([3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4])
```

```
Output:
[3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4]
[3, 3, 3, 4]
[4]
6
```

How could I update the implementation to include the more general solution of removing 3+ consecutive numbers. I am thinking about tracking the start and end index of the consecutive duplicates, then subsetting the list. However, not sure how to implement that. Here are the tests that should work.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    test1 = [3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4]
    print(balls(test1))
    #Output should be 6

    test2 = [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
    print(balls(test2))
    #Output should be 8

    test3 = [5, 7, 8, 3]
    print(balls(test3))
    #Output should be 0
```

Comment: I remember a very similar question from yesterday. Is this some ongoing coding contest or homework?

Comment: @tobias_k maybe that was mine? I linked it above. Also, not homework. Just working through some Algo exercises, while trying to learn. Also, do you have the link for it? I'd take a look. maybe there is a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
def remove_consecutive(l, length):
    amount = len(l)
    count = 1
    start = 0
    current = l[0]
    i = 1
    while i < len(l):
        if l[i] == current:
            count += 1
        else:
            if count >= length:
                for i in range(count):
                    l.pop(start)
                start = 0
                i = 0
                current = l[0]
            else:
                start = i         
            current = l[i]
            count = 1
        i+=1
    if count >= length:
        for i in range(count):
            l.pop(start)
    return amount - len(l)
```

Wuff, i got it. My brain is kinda stinky lately so it took so long.

Comment: You shouldn't post multiple answers unless they provide different solutions/approaches. In this case you should have edited your previous answer with this solution as the first version did not answer the question properly.

Comment: You should also point out your solution modifies the original list.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code, it works well. But I think there may be better ways to achieve higher efficiency.

```
def remove_consecutive(lst):
    len_init = len(lst)
    contain_tuplets = True
    while contain_tuplets:
        for i in range(len(lst)-2):
            indices_to_pop = []
            if lst[i]==lst[i+1]==lst[i+2]:
                indices_to_pop.extend([i, i+1, i+2])
                for j in range(i+3,len(lst)):
                    if lst[j] == lst[i]:
                        indices_to_pop.append(j)
                    else:
                        break
                [lst.pop(i) for _ in indices_to_pop]
                contain_tuplets = True
                break
        else:
            contain_tuplets = False

    count_removed_numbers = len_init - len(lst)
    return count_removed_numbers, lst
```

test case1:

```
lst = [3,3,4,4,4,4,3,2]
remove_consecutive(lst)
```

output

```
(7, [2])
```

test case 2:

```
lst = [2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1]
remove_consecutive(lst)
```

output:

```
(6, [1])
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def remove_consecutive(l, length):
    amount = 0
    count = 1
    current = l[0]
    for i in range(1, len(l)):
        if l[i] == current:
           
            count += 1
            if count > length:
                amount += 1
            elif count == length:
                amount += length
               
        else:
            current = l[i]
            count = 1
    return amount
```

Comment: unfortunately this does not work. [2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1] should print 6, because first 1,1,1 removed (3), then 2,2,2 (another 3). final list is [1]. In your code it prints 3. which does not even work for the first simpler problem with 3 consecutive numbers.